# JQuery only working on Firefox

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating an HTML front page for users to view our 'How To' documents, the pdfs are fembeded onto the page to create a preview using the below JQuery. This is working fine in Firefox however will not work in IE or Chrome, any help is appreciated, Thanks

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        "use strict";
        $('.btn').click(function() {
            var idToSRC = './HTA_' + this.id + '.pdf';
            $('#viewer').attr('src', idToSRC);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Probably because the adobe plugin is not installed for those browsers?

Comment: @techfoobar I thought Chrome had a built-in PDF viewer now.

Comment: Did you check console for any error?

Comment: @techfoobar Yeah Chrome comes with its own PDF viewer

Comment: @The-Val I have and nothing shows, I have use JSLint and it comes back with no issues

Comment: Is `#viewer` an iframe? If you watch the network debugger, does the request for the PDF even happen? If you debug the code, is `$('#viewer')` actually matching something on Chrome? If so, can you change the `src` to another website or something else?

Comment: #viewer an embed of the file, i am not using an iframe to do it .`<embed id="viewer" src="HTA_001.pdf" width="500" height="680">`

Comment: Not sure it would mess up the whole thing but is use strict mode supported by other browsers ?

Comment: Depending on the browser, you can't generally change the src of an embed tag dynamically. Instead, you need to replace it with a new embed tag. See these threads:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493706/javascript-changing-src-attribute-of-a-embed-tag
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646413/how-to-change-the-value-of-embed-src-with-javascript

Comment: @Shinosha I have tried with and without, this was suggested by JSLint thus the reason i added.

Comment: @SpAm - I'm a bit of a JQuery newbie how would i use that with my example above? sorry if thats cheeky

Comment: Answer is not mine to respond but watch Durgaprasad Budhwani'post in the link SpAm provided, it should give you a good idea what to do.

Comment: @redratedcoding See my posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the JQuery clone() method (the urls I used are example PDFs):

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
<button type="button" class="btn">Change Src</button>
<div>
    <embed id="viewer" src="http://www.education.gov.yk.ca/pdf/pdf-test.pdf" width="500" height="680"></embed>
</div>

 $(document).ready(function() {
        "use strict";
        $('.btn').click(function() {
            //var idToSRC = './HTA_' + this.id + '.pdf';
            var idToSRC = "http://www.reservoirminerals.com/files/doc_downloads/test.pdf";
            var $viewerDiv = $('#viewer').parent();          
            var viewerClone = $('#viewer').clone().attr('src', idToSRC);
            $viewerDiv.html(viewerClone);
        }); });
```

See it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/W32RA/2/

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't worry about that, accepting is enough, thank-you. :)