# How to change the 'src' attribute using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I am trying to remove the `src` attribute from an `embed` tag of  youtube video player in a slider .

It works fine in Fire Fox but do not work in chrome and in IE the video itself is not showing .

here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/zppu6/3/) .

and the script that I am trying to use is here

**Script**

```
$(document).on('click', '.transparent-btns_nav', function (event) {
    video = $('.transparent-btns1_on').find('object').length;
    if ($('#video1').parents('li').hasClass('transparent-btns1_on')) {
        $('object').find('#video1').attr("src", "http://www.youtube.com/v/PLOUfmig96M?version=3&enablejsapi=1&hl=es_ES&rel=0&color1=0x2b405b&color2=0x6b8ab6&fs=1&border=1&autoplay=1");
    } else {
        $('object').find('#video1').attr("src", "");
    }

});
```

**Edit 1**

I think this issue can only be resolved by writing the whole  tag using `clone` . I read in [this-->Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)
got it from one of the *[StackAnswers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646413/how-to-change-the-value-of-embed-src-with-javascript)*

Comment: try using `.prop()` instead `.attr()`.

Comment: Btw, for me its showing video in FF and Chrome (over Linux)

Comment: yes it shows video in FF and Chrome but in IE no . And I tried `prop()` same problem do not work in chrome 36.0 (over windows)