# Display a pdf file in the browser with sails

Tags: html, node.js, sails.js

I have some documents in a directory and I want to show one embedded in the browser, I save the path of the document in a table and I can read the path from that table and download the document, but I can't figure out how to show the file in the browser.
I'm using the following code to send the file:

```
  loadDocument: async function (req,res){

  var SkipperDisk = require('skipper-disk');
  var fileAdapter = SkipperDisk(/* optional opts */);

  var fd = await Documents.find(
      {
        where: {id:'1'},
        select: ['uploadFileFd']
      }
  ).limit(1);

  let uploadFileFd = fd[0]["uploadFileFd"];

  var fileStream = fileAdapter.read(uploadFileFd);

  fileStream.on('error', function (err){
    return res.serverError(err);
  });

  res.contentType("application/pdf");

  res.set("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "file"+ fd[0]["id"]+".pdf");

  fileStream.pipe(res);

  },
```

I want to call the function and load the pdf file in the browser, preferably without reloading all the page.

Comment: Really depends what you want for the user. You could open the PDF in a new tab when a button is clicked, calling something like `www.example.com/loaddocument/foobar` as the href of an anchor tag, combine that with target _blank for a new tab or without to replace the current content or you could put the PDF into an embed tag, an iframe to be old school. Loads of options.

Comment: I want to open the PDF into an embed tag

Comment: In that case, you are looking for PDF.js my friend. Online demo: http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

GitHub: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: Or just embed it, `<embed src="http://example.com/loaddocument/foobar" width="90%" height="90%" 
type="application/pdf">` you could set the source dynamically.

Comment: I know that I can use <object> <iframe> or <embed> to show a pdf in the browser, but I'm looking for a way to send the pdf that I have in the server and showing it in the browser, because currently I can download the pdf but that's not what I want.

Comment: What do you mean by send rather than download?

Comment: I have some pdf files in my server, I want to show them in the browser according to the options that the user gave me, currently I take that options and I download the file, what I want instead of download the file is to show it in the browser

Comment: OK, embed will still do this for you. So what you would to do is write a small bit of JavaScript on the client side, that puts the options into a request string, then create an embed tag that uses the full url including the request parameters as the src. Then the embed tag will display that pdf.

Comment: So your src would be something like http://example.com/loaddocument?option1=foo&option2=bar take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646413/how-to-change-the-value-of-embed-src-with-javascript then to see how you would change or update the embed tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.
First I have to create a way to serve the static folder where the files are located, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543252/how-to-serve-a-static-folder-in-sails-js).

Then I modify the code to send the data encoded as base64 using 'base64-stream':

```
      var readStream = fs.createReadStream(uploadFileFd);
      readStream.on('open', function () {
          readStream.pipe(new Base64Encode()).pipe(res);
      });
      readStream.on('error', function(err) {
        res.end(err);
      });
```

Finally I show the pdf file in the browser as follows:

```
     .done(function(data){
          var parent = $('embed#pdf').parent();
          var newElement = "<embed src=data:application/pdf;base64,"+data+" id='pdf' width='100%' height='1200'>";
          $('embed#pdf').remove();
          parent.append(newElement);
        })
```

Now I can display a pdf file in the browser embedded in my own page, thanks to all the people that try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Clients browsers will download the pdf without trying to open the built-in PDF viewer (ie, Chrome) because of the `Content-disposition: attachment` header that you're sending - try using ***inline*** instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

```js
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="file' + fd[0]["id"] + '.pdf"');
```