# Updating flash content src tag to swap out an animation

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple `<embed>` tag for my flash animation in Chrome, and I want to swap out the animation dynamically:

```
<embed id="test" src="init.swf" width="550" height="400"> </embed>
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("test").src = "test.swf";
      console.log("Swapped");
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

I expected `init.swf` to play for five seconds, before switching over to `test.swf`.

Instead, it keeps playing `init.swf` indefinitely. Meanwhile, the JS console shows `Swapped`, so the code is running. Even stranger, the element inspector shows the `src` tag updating, but the animation does not change.

Changing the `width` from either the inspector or my JS function works as expected, but `src` is not updated.

How can I replace this animation with another one?

Comment: Show us your code! Otherwise the best I can do is point you towards `document.getElementById()`, and wish you luck!

Comment: I'm sorry. ```<embed id="test" src="game.swf" width="1366" height="768"> </embed>
<script>
    document.getElementById("test").src=prompt("What is your swf file called?")
</script>``` is my code so far.

Comment: But it works fine if you hard-code the path in the `embed` element?

Comment: Hey the result of `prompt("What is your swf file called?")` has single single quatation around it. So, first trim those quotes and then implant the result in your `embed`s src... Worked in my test.

Comment: It's time for you to embrace HTML5.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I was able to reproduce your problem in Chrome and took the liberty of editing your post with some additional details and an example that's easier to run (feel free to update if you don't find it representative). It appears that this may be a plugin integration issue rather than a problem with your code: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646413/how-to-change-the-value-of-embed-src-with-javascript) which instead recommends swapping out the whole `<embed>` with a new one.

Comment: @thatotherguy Could you please explain why the code you added does not match the OP's code?

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica OP's code required typing in data which quickly became tedious in testing. The problem manifested with both dynamically entered and statically assigned strings.